# No coordinates from GDAL index in MySQL

Tags: gdal, mysql

I have run the gdaltindex command with output to a MySQL table, however only a list of file name are

```
gdaltindex -lyr_name Source_raster_idx -f MYSQL MySQL:mapDB,host=localhost,user=admin,password=pass */*/*/*/*.jp2
```

It loads the filename and path into the column named "location", However, I don't see where the spatial coordinates are supposed to be stored.

Am I supposed to add a column for this?

Comment: Coordinates, or simple bounding boxes of the footprints of images as polygons, are supposed to be stored into a geometry column of the table. Does your new MySQL table miss the geometry column?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have a geometry column. I've also tried the -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=shape switch with no positive results.

Comment: Does command create good index if you use for example shapefile or GeoPackage as outputformat?

Comment: Yes it does. I actually got it working now. However I also need a way to add additional attributes for each index entry, preferably during creation. Is there a way to add this?

Comment: Not directly, all you can do is documented https://gdal.org/programs/gdaltindex.html. You must use the filename as an ID and add attributes later.